# PyCharm giving strange result, is it a memory / pointer issue?

Tags: python, pointers, pycharm

I have some Python code as follows in PyCharm:

```
pd_mrc_RMS = []
for i in range(len(pd_diff_ratioRMS)):
    mrc_now = mrc_diff_ratioRMS[i]
    pd_now = pd_diff_ratioRMS[i]
    pd_mrc_RMS_now = np.sqrt(mrc_now**2 + pd_now**2)
    pd_mrc_RMS.append(pd_mrc_RMS_now)
```

I have noticed that sometimes, `mrc_now` and/or `pd_now` can be `inf` or `NaN` which would cause `pd_mrc_RMS_now` to be `inf` or `NaN` as well.  This is logical.  However for a specific case, that code above causes the last value of `pd_mrc_RMS` to be that of the last value in `pd_diff_ratioRMS`.  Nowhere do I have such command.  I only append into the array `pd_mrc_RMS_now`, which is calculated off `pd_now`.  To clarify things, in that case, the values of the other arrays are:

```
pd_diff_ratioRMS = [inf,
                    0.7343642741825436,
                    0.7102599599923878,
                    0.22130907979104325,
                    0.01582110950187491,
                    0.4487684369819055,
                    0.07653438892240305,
                    0.2273945352145594]
mrc_diff_ratioRMS = [inf,
                     inf,
                     inf,
                     nan,
                     inf,
                     inf,
                     inf,
                     inf]
```

And the code gives me:

```
pd_diff_ratioRMS = [inf,
                    inf,
                    inf,
                    nan,
                    inf,
                    inf,
                    inf,
                    0.2273945352145594]
```

I change the code into this hoping to avoid the strange phenomenon:

```
pd_mrc_RMS = []
for i in range(len(pd_diff_ratioRMS)):
    mrc_now = mrc_diff_ratioRMS[i]
    pd_now = pd_diff_ratioRMS[i]
    cond1 = float('-inf') < mrc_now < float('inf')
    cond2 = float('-inf') < pd_now < float('inf')
    pd_mrc_RMS_now = 0.
    if cond1 and cond2:
        pd_mrc_RMS_now = np.sqrt(mrc_now**2 + pd_now**2)
    else:
        pd_mrc_RMS_now = float('inf')
    pd_mrc_RMS.append(pd_mrc_RMS_now)
```

The problem still doesn't go away.  I then change it into something I thought foolproof:

```
pd_mrc_RMS = []
for i in range(len(pd_diff_ratioRMS)):
    mrc_now = mrc_diff_ratioRMS[i]
    pd_now = pd_diff_ratioRMS[i]
    cond1 = float('-inf') < mrc_now < float('inf')
    cond2 = float('-inf') < pd_now < float('inf')
    pd_mrc_RMS_now = 0.
    if cond1 and cond2:
        pd_mrc_RMS_now = np.sqrt(mrc_now**2 + pd_now**2)
        pd_mrc_RMS.append(pd_mrc_RMS_now)
    else:
        pd_mrc_RMS_now = float('inf')
        pd_mrc_RMS.append(1.0)
```

To my horror, this is the result it gives me:

```
pd_diff_ratioRMS = [1.0,
                    1.0,
                    1.0,
                    1.0,
                    1.0,
                    1.0,
                    1.0,
                    0.2273945352145594]
```

That value should not be there by any possible way.  I have run out of imagination on why this happens.  I see no error in my code.  It checks out on all other cases except this pair of `pd_diff_ratioRMS` and `mrc_diff_ratioRMS`.  Any pointer will be appreciated.

==========================================================================

In my effort to brute force a solution, the following code is added after the code above:

```
# fixing strange issue
for i in range(len(pd_mrc_RMS)):
    mrc_now = mrc_diff_ratioRMS[i]
    pd_now = pd_diff_ratioRMS[i]
    cond1 = not(float('-inf') < mrc_now < float('inf'))
    cond2 = not(float('-inf') < pd_now < float('inf'))
    if cond1 or cond2:
        pd_mrc_RMS[i] = float('inf')
pd_mrc_RMS[7] = 1.0
```

To my utter surprise, `pd_mrc_RMS[7]` stubbornly remains at `0.2273945352145594`.  I ran out of ideas for real.

In another attempt, I switch from `np.sqrt` to `math.sqrt` and the issue still remains.

These are the imports I use for the code and I am using Python 3.8:

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageChops
import numpy as np
import math
```

For those looking to reproduce the issue, I am using Python 3.8.0.  I use this code in another file, and still witness the same problem (`math.sqrt` or `np.sqrt`):

```
import numpy as np
import math

pd_diff_ratioRMS = [float('inf'),
                    0.7343642741825436,
                    0.7102599599923878,
                    0.22130907979104325,
                    0.01582110950187491,
                    0.4487684369819055,
                    0.07653438892240305,
                    0.2273945352145594]

mrc_diff_ratioRMS = [float('inf'),
                     float('inf'),
                     float('inf'),
                     float('NaN'),
                     float('inf'),
                     float('inf'),
                     float('inf'),
                     float('inf')]

#pd_mrc_RMS = []
pd_mrc_RMS = [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]
for i in range(len(pd_diff_ratioRMS)):
    mrc_now = mrc_diff_ratioRMS[i]
    pd_now = pd_diff_ratioRMS[i]
    #pd_mrc_RMS_now = np.sqrt(mrc_now ** 2 + pd_now ** 2)
    pd_mrc_RMS_now = math.sqrt(mrc_now ** 2 + pd_now ** 2)
    #pd_mrc_RMS.append(pd_mrc_RMS_now)
    pd_mrc_RMS[i] = pd_mrc_RMS_now
pd_mrc_RMS[7] = 1.0
pd_mrc_RMS[7] = 2.0
pd_mrc_RMS[7] = 3.0
```

The only thing I haven't done so far is resetting my PC.  But seeing it again on another file tells me that it wouldn't.  Switching from an append to an assignment still doesn't work.  Straight assignments afterwards don't help either.  Switching Python version also doesn't help.

Running the code above in a new project shows no error.  `0.2273945352145594` never gets appended to the array as expected.  I strongly suspect an issue with PyCharm.  Any idea?

Comment: `np.sqrt` returns a mutable object. If that mutable object is mutated, that change will be reflected everywhere that its contained. I don't see where such a mutation is happening in this code, but that's my bet.

Comment: @Carcigenicate, now that you mention it, all the `1.0` are `float` that the strange value is a `float64`.  The mystery only deepens.

Comment: This could be verified by `print(id(pd_mrc_RMS[-1]), id(pd_diff_ratioRMS[-1]))`. In the problem case, if those two numbers match, I'm right.

Comment: I have placed that line after the first code and second (brute force fix).  These are the values they give: 140701133279024 140701133278608 / 140701694304816 140701133278608.

Comment: Do you know why there is a change in the value of `pd_mrc_RMS[-1]`?

Comment: I cannot reproduce. The original code gives a list of `inf` on my Python 3.6. Please give a true [mcve] *including the import lines*.

Comment: @CaTx The change of value is expected since all floats should have different `id`s (location in memory). The fact that the other one matches though means that it's the same exact object in memory each time. Sorry, I'm starting work soon, and I don't have enough experience with numpy to be able to eyeball-debug this. This still smells like mutable objects though. A [mcve] would likely help anyone else who sees your question to help you. There should be one complete set of code here that reproduces the problem; imports and all.

Comment: @SergeBallesta, I have added the imports to the question.  Python 3.8 is used.

Comment: No it is not enough! `inf` and `nan` have to come from something. A [mcve] is something that we can copy and paste and should exhibit the erroneous behaviour. Currently when I try to assemble the different parts and fill the missing declarations, I get correct results.

Comment: @SergeBallesta, I have included your requested item.

Comment: And in works fine under Pycharm using a Python 3.8.4 and numpy 1.19.0 ...

Comment: I just restarted my PC, and it is still there.  Will try changing Python version now.  My numpy version is 1.19.1 does that change anything?

Comment: Switching the interpreter to Python 3.6 in and resetting PyCharm doesn't help either.  Trying a new project with the minimal code above now.

Comment: The issue never shows up when running the mininal code in a new project.  I am at a loss.

Comment: I would like to thank you for all the help so far.